# iBooks not responding when opening book

Tags: books

Just recently, an iBook I've been reading for a long time made iBooks not respond when I double clicked it to open. I've tried navigating to it several different ways, but it doesn't work. For some reason, however, the iBook still works perfectly on my phone, and secondary computer. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem, and in my case the books that I cannot open are shown as having been downloaded from iCloud but have a size of 0kb. Perhaps this has to do with iBooks counting undownloaded books as downloaded? Is there a way to reset it all?

Comment: @Kenji I didn't have that issue, but I fixed my issue by waiting. The book opened after about an hour of not responding.

Comment: I see. Perhaps we have different issues then.